# Receiving syntax error with INSERT DATEDIFF

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am receiving this error, and not being to insert DATEDIFF into the database.  I can't seem to find the problem.  I tried checking the syntax.  Can anyone help please?

```
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$pdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pdate']);
$mdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['mdate']);
$amt = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['amt']);
$first = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first']);
$last = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last']);
$pid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pid']);
$cno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cno']);
$madd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['madd']);
$bene = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bene']);
$swc = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['swc']);
$bacc = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bacc']);
$bank = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bank']);
$badd = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['badd']);
$bno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['bno']);      

$sql="INSERT INTO contacts (
      nodays, interest, pdate, mdate, amt, first, last,
      pid, cno, madd, bene, swc, bacc, bank, badd, bno
    ) 
    VALUES (
      DATEDIFF($mdate,$pdate) AS nodays,
      (DATEDIFF($mdate,$pdate) * $amt / 365 * 0.1) AS interest,
      '$pdate','$mdate','$amt','$first','$last',
      '$pid','$cno','$madd','$bene','$swc','$bacc','$bank','$badd','$bno'
    )";



    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "Client record has been added to the database!";

    mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to execute 2 queries at the same time - only delimited by comma. That does not work. Seperagte them and execute them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting 2 more columns into contacts:

You say `INSERT INTO CONTACTS` with all the columns, but then you use 
`SELECT *, DATEDIFF...  FROM CONTACTS`. So you try to insert more columns into the same table.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to calculate the `nodays` and `interest` as you do the insert, this should work:

```
INSERT INTO contacts (
  nodays, interest, pdate, mdate, amt, first, last,
  pid, cno, madd, bene, swc, bacc, bank, badd, bno
) 
VALUES (
  DATEDIFF($mdate,$pdate),
  (DATEDIFF($mdate,$pdate) * $amt / 365 * 0.1),
  '$pdate','$mdate','$amt','$first','$last',
  '$pid','$cno','$madd','$bene','$swc','$bacc','$bank','$badd','$bno'
);
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct I am trying to calculate the nodays and interest and hoping that it will record into the database.
It's showing error showing nodays cannot be null

Comment: @Alex Double check that all the values are present.. if `$mdate` or `$pdate` are `null`, then I believe `DATEDIFF` returns `null`.

Comment: @Alex Also it looks like you are running the query twice; there should only be one call to `mysqli_query()`